# Ms-Access to Excel Late Binging VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, late-binding

I am currently using late binding from MS Access 2016 to MS Excel:
The conditional formatting code does not perform the required job, but does not complain of an error when run.

I am able to create an Excel sheet and edit the sheet, but currently am unable to create conditional formatting in the excel sheet. I have attempted to define the variables below, but feel as though I am missing something.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SendEmailXLS()
    Dim appExcel As Object
    Dim objActiveWkb As Object
    Dim rng As Object
    Const xlConditionValueLowestValue As Long = 1
    Const xlConditionValuePercentile As Long = 5
    Const xlConditionValueHighestValue As Long = 2

    DoCmd.OpenReport "REPORT_XLS", acViewReport, WhereCondition:="EmailAddress='" & Me.User_Login & "'"
    DoCmd.OutputTo ObjectType:=acOutputReport, ObjectName:="REPORT_XLS", OutputFormat:=acFormatXLS, Outputfile:="\\XXX\REPORT_XLS.xls"

    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appExcel.Visible = False
    appExcel.Application.Workbooks.Open ("\\XXX\REPORT_XLS.xls")

    Set objActiveWkb = appExcel.Application.ActiveWorkbook

    With objActiveWkb

        .Worksheets(1).Cells.Select
        .Worksheets(1).Columns("A:AI").Font.Size = 8
        .Worksheets(1).Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
        .Worksheets(1).Columns("A:AH").HorizontalAlignment = -4108
        .Worksheets(1).Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 8
        .Worksheets(1).Columns("AJ").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Worksheets(1).Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 0.1
        .Worksheets(1).Columns("A").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Worksheets(1).Columns("K:L").NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
        .Worksheets(1).Columns("N:AF").NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
        .Worksheets(1).Columns("AG:AH").NumberFormat = "0.0%"
        .Worksheets(1).Rows(1).EntireRow.Insert
        .Worksheets(1).Range("B2:AI2").Interior.Color = RGB(50, 100, 20)
        .Worksheets(1).Range("O1:Q1").Interior.Color = RGB(50, 100, 20)
        .Worksheets(1).Columns("A").Borders.Weight = 2
        .Worksheets(1).Columns("O:Q").Borders.Weight = 2
        .Worksheets(1).Columns("U:AC").Borders.Weight = 2
        .Worksheets(1).Columns("AJ").Borders.Weight = 2
        .Worksheets(1).Range("U1:AC1").Interior.Color = RGB(50, 100, 20)

        Set rng = .Worksheets(1).Columns("AD:AD")

        rng.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
        rng.FormatConditions(rng.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
        xlConditionValueLowestValue
        With rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
            .Color = 7039480
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
        xlConditionValuePercentile
        rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
        With rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
            .Color = 8711167
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
        xlConditionValueHighestValue
        With rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
            .Color = 8109667
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With        

    End With

    objActiveWkb.Close savechanges:=True
    appExcel.Application.Quit
    Set objActiveWkb = Nothing: Set appExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Error does not occur when using AppExcel.Selection but job is not performed either.

```
.Worksheets(1).Range("AD:AD").Select
appExcel.Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
appExcel.Selection.FormatConditions(appExcel.Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    appExcel.Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
    1
With appExcel.Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
    .Color = 7039480
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
appExcel.Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
    5
appExcel.Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
With appExcel.Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
    .Color = 8711167
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
appExcel.Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
    2
With appExcel.Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
    .Color = 8109667
    .TintAndShade = 0
 End With
```

Comment: You are running all this under `On Error Resume Next`, so it's no surprise you don't get any errors.

Comment: Thank you! When removing ]On Error Resume Next,] I began to notice errors in the coede. I will work through the errors over this weekend.

Comment: At this time the code errors out at Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3 This is strange as when I use this code in excel, it performs as required. Any Ideas on how to run this in access to get this to  work?

Comment: It's because `Selection` is an Excel object that Access VBA doesn't know about. You could try `appExcel.Selection`, but it would be much better to use Tim's suggestion and use a `Range` object.

Comment: Andre, I have updated the code as seen above. It appears to be continuing to give me an error per description above. Do you have an idea of what may fix the error? The second section of the code using  "AppExcel.Selection" does not give me an error, but will not perform the action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't know what (eg) `xlConditionValueLowestValue` represents - it's a built-in Excel constant, but to your code (without a VB project reference to Excel) it just looks like an undeclared variable. The compiler would have helpfully complained about this, if you used `Option Explicit` at the top of every module.

If you were using early binding, the compiler would look at the Excel object library to try to resolve any of these values.

So, when using late binding you need to tell your code about these Excel constants, typically by creating matching constants in your own code.  Alternatively you can substitute the numeric values, which you can find from the VB editor in Excel, and likely also via Google.

**EDIT**: try this change

Replace this:

```
.Worksheets(1).Columns("AD:AD").Select
```

with

```
Set rng = .Worksheets(1).Columns("AD:AD")
```

then replace all following instances of `Selection` with `rng`

Comment: Ill add on to this with a widely annoying HUGE ASS list of excel constants lol

Comment: Tim, Thank you so much for the reply. I had supplemented as per your answer although it still does not create the conditional formatting. ex: xlConditionValueLowestValue = 1, xlConditionValuePercentile =5, xlConditionValueHighestValue =2

Comment: Also, If I input Option Explicit at the beginning of every module it begins to complain about "appExcel" as Variable Not Defined.

Comment: If it complains of undeclared variables then define them?

Comment: Tim, Thank you. I had defined all variables. Although, no matter what I do, I am unable to get the specified section (condition formatting ) to work. I am unsure what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: Can you update your question with a (smallest possible) complete set of code which reproduces the issue you're having?  Without an exact path to follow it's difficult to say what your problem might  be.

Comment: Please let me know if this may be sufficient to help identify the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not fix the issue. The excel document now no longer Selects Range ("AD:AD").

Comment: My point was that you shouldn't need to select the range in order to apply the formatting

Comment: Tim, I have updated the code. Everything appears to be running, although the conditional formatting does not execute. I have updated two different ways that I have attempted to run the code. Both return no error.

Comment: Tim, I have found the issue! The reason I have not been seeing these changes is because during the save process the excel document would convert the xls file. How do I tell excel to convert the file on save to compatibility mode. I have added the save code above t hat I am using.

Comment: objActiveWkb.Close savechanges:=True
appExcel.Application.Quit
Set objActiveWkb = Nothing
Set appExcel = Nothing

Answer (score 2):

Here is a handy dandy list of excel constants you can create a global definition module with. Check whats here versus what youre using.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mcxx9byernn67qh/AABmCwBn11_36VqqlsXGtq2Wa?dl=0

Comment: if youre having issues downloading let me know.

Comment: Quick reference for these cases. Thanks for sharing :-)