# Same Access Database produces error on another computer

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a Subroutine that produces an Excel spreadhseet.  I have Access 2016 at home and at work we also use 2016.

Here are the References

[image]

It works fine at work but When I try running the program at home  I get an error 1004 and it stops on this line:

.Papersize = xlPaperLetter

Here is the complete code:

```
Private Sub Generate_FS(Optional dbFullPath As String)


Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim WB As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Dim db As DAO.Database

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsCategories As DAO.Recordset

Dim xlCellAddr As Range

Dim i, M, n As Integer
Dim iCategory_rec_count As Integer

Dim iInsert_row_count As Integer
Dim iCols(1 To 10) As Integer

Dim strFileName As String
Dim strLocation As String
Dim strXLStartCell As String
Dim strCat As String


Dim strSheet As String
Dim iBottom As Integer

iBottom = 0

strSheet = "FINANCIAL STATUS"

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set WB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = WB.Sheets("Sheet1")


If Len(dbFullPath) < 1 Then
    Set db = CurrentDb
Else
    Set db = OpenDatabase(dbFullPath, True)
End If



xlApp.Visible = False



SyncActiveFile
Form_sfAFvsSTACY.Requery

Call CreateFSTemplate(WB, "Sheet1")



If Me.lblWhere.Caption = "" Then
    Set rsCategories = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_Budget_Authorization ORDER BY SORT")
Else
    Set rsCategories = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_Budget_Authorization WHERE BA_Category " & Me.lblWhere.Caption & " ORDER BY SORT")
End If

Debug.Print "SELECT * FROM tbl_Budget_Authorization WHERE BA_Category " & Me.lblWhere.Caption & " ORDER BY SORT"


If Not (rsCategories.EOF And rsCategories.BOF) Then

rsCategories.MoveFirst



    For n = 1 To DCount("BA_Category", "tbl_Budget_Authorization", "BA_CATEGORY " & Me.lblWhere.Caption) ', "FY='" & cboFY & "'") 'rsCategories.RecordCount






        strCat = rsCategories!BA_Category

        Set rs = GetFSSection(strCat)





        iCategory_rec_count = Val(Nz(DLookup("CAT_COUNT", "qFS_Category_Count", "Category='" & rsCategories!BA_Category & "'"), 0))
        iInsert_row_count = iCategory_rec_count - 1

        Set xlCellAddr = xlSheet.Range("D1:D5000").Find("TOTAL " & rsCategories![BA_Category], lookat:=xlPart)


        If iInsert_row_count > 0 Then

            For i = 1 To iInsert_row_count

               xlSheet.Rows(xlCellAddr.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown

            Next
        End If



          Set xlCellAddr = xlSheet.Range("D2:D5000").Find("TOTAL " & rsCategories![BA_Category], lookat:=xlPart)



          strXLStartCell = "B" & (xlCellAddr.Row - iCategory_rec_count)

        'Copy the recordset
        xlSheet.Range(strXLStartCell).CopyFromRecordset rs

        rsCategories.MoveNext



    Next


       iBottom = xlCellAddr.Row


End If


'Format
xlSheet.Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
xlSheet.Columns("E:I").NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"


'perform running balance separately and obtain 'available balance'
Call CreateRunningBalance(WB, strSheet, iBottom)

    'Make working section into a table
    With xlSheet

        .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("B2:I" & iBottom), , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
        .ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium12"
    End With



With xlSheet
    .Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Columns("I:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With


'**ADD Budget Authorization Total and Available Balance
Dim cBA_Total As Currency
Dim cAvailBalance As Currency

cBA_Total = Nz(DSum("Budget_Authorization", "tbl_Budget_Authorization", "FY='" & cboFY & "'"), 0)

xlSheet.Range("A" & iBottom + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "Budget Authorization: " & Format(cBA_Total, "Currency")
'Available balance gets written from CreateRunningBalance

With xlSheet.Range("A" & iBottom + 1 & ":I" & iBottom + 2).Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                '.Color = RGB(177, 160, 199) 'light purple
                .Color = RGB(79, 0, 158) ' dark purple
            End With


            With xlSheet.Range("A" & iBottom + 1 & ":I" & iBottom + 2).Font
                .Name = "Arial Black"
                .Size = 11
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Bold = True
            End With





xlSheet.Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "J02HQ2 FINANCIAL STATUS AS OF " & Now()

'Format the header like the CATEGORY rows

            With xlSheet.Range("A1:I1").Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .Color = RGB(79, 0, 158)
            End With

             With xlSheet.Range("A1:I1").Font
                .Name = "Arial Black"
                .Size = 14
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Bold = True
            End With



            With xlSheet.Range("A2:I2").Font
                .Name = "Arial Black"
                .Size = 11
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Bold = True
            End With






xlSheet.Range("A6").Select


WB.RefreshAll


strFileName = "J02HQ2 FINANCIAL_STATUS_" & DateString & ".xlsx"

    strLocation = Environ("userprofile") & "\Documents\Financial Status\"

    ensurePath strLocation


'======================================
    With xlSheet.PageSetup

        .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$2" 'This property sets the first 2 rows to repeat on every page

        .Zoom = False

        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = False

        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter

        .PrintQuality = 600
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Draft = False
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed



        .LeftMargin = xlApp.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .RightMargin = xlApp.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TopMargin = xlApp.InchesToPoints(0.25)

       .BottomMargin = .Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
       .FooterMargin = .Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
       .CenterFooter = "Page &P"



        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True

    End With


'======================================


   'For Row 2
    With xlSheet.Range("A2:I2").Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13855654
    End With


    With WB
        .TableStyles("TableStyleMedium6").Duplicate ("ToPurple")
        .TableStyles("ToPurple").TableStyleElements(xlWholeTable).Clear

    End With

    With WB.TableStyles("ToPurple").TableStyleElements(xlWholeTable).Interior
        .PatternColor = RGB(207, 175, 231) 'lighter purple
        .Color = RGB(166, 107, 211) 'darker purple
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    WB.TableStyles("ToPurple").TableStyleElements(xlRowStripe1).Clear

    With WB.TableStyles("ToPurple").TableStyleElements(xlRowStripe1).Interior
        .Color = RGB(207, 175, 231) 'lighter purple
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    xlSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "ToPurple"


'======================================================================


Debug.Print strLocation & strFileName

WB.SaveAs FileName:=strLocation & strFileName


'Cleanup

Set xlSheet = Nothing
For Each WB In xlApp.Workbooks
    WB.Close False
Next

xlApp.Quit
PresentExcel (strLocation & strFileName)


GoTo Exit_Hand



Exit_Hand:
Set xlSheet = Nothing


Set rs = Nothing
Set rsCategories = Nothing

Set xlCellAddr = Nothing


Set db = Nothing
Set WB = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing




End Sub
```

Comment: https://support.pcmiler.com/en/support/solutions/articles/19000047036-what-does-error-1004-programmatic-access-to-visual-basic-project-is-not-trusted-mean-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s important to post as much of your code as possible.  The answer may be discovered by someone like @Santosh who recognized, in this case that the Excel object was having a problem with my printer. That’s why it worked at work but not at home.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 .Order = xlDownThenOver
 .Orientation = xlLandscape
 .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
```

to as MS access doesn't recognize those enums

```
  .Order = 1
  .Orientation = 2
  .PaperSize = 1
```

[See this for quick reference of excel constants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882188/2227085)

Comment: I did as you said and I got the error "Excel object model not supported" - so I set my xlApp as Object instead of Excel.Application.  Then it didn't know what xlPart was, so I downloaded ALL of the Excel Constants and added them to a module.  And guess what?  The exact same error:  1004 - It doesn't know what to do with the PageSetup papersize!  So what the hay?

Comment: Try this `Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` to `Set xlApp = New Excel.Application`

Comment: I made the correction, but still got the same error.  Concerned why it works with the Access installation at work if I have to make all these corrections. What will happen?  Will it break there?

Comment: Verify your printer settings. Seems like printer  doesn't supports the xlPaperLetter  . See the note https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pagesetup-papersize-property-excel

Comment: What printer doesn’t support letter size 8.5. X 11?

Comment: Your idea prompted me to realize that maybe it could take a 'default' value if I left it out, so I commented out .PaperSize and it worked.   Thank you!

Comment: @monty327 Ok great!